# awk select input files from list

Tags: awk

basic Awk question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere:

I have a folder of 50000 txt files, from which I would like to run AWK searches on a subset.  I've saved the filenames I want to limit the search to in a separate document. This would greatly speed up the search, which at the moment looks like this:

```
awk -F "searchTerm" '{print NF-1}' data/output/*>> output.txt
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your file containing the subset that you want to search is called `subset.txt` and its content has this format (each file on a separate line):

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
...
fileN.txt
```

Then this will do the trick:

```
awk -F "searchTerm" '{print NF-1}' $(<subset.txt) >> output.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `$(<subset.txt)` will supply the subset list of files to `awk` as input. (See Jonathan Leffler's comment below)

---

I should also point out that `-F "searchTerm"` is actually setting the Field Separator (limiter used by awk on each line) to `searchTerm`. If you want to print the Number of Fields - 1 on each line that contains "searchTerm", do:

```
awk '/searchTerm/ {print NF-1}' $(cat subset.txt) >> output.txt
```

Comment: In `bash`, you can avoid the `cat` process with `$(<subset.txt)` which avoids a sub-shell and a process.

Comment: The above will fail for filenames containing spaces, globbing characters, etc., etc..... The right way to do it is `while IFS= read -r file; do awk '...' "$file"; done < subset.txt`

Comment: @Ed `while read...` while fail on filenames containing newlines.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Absolutely. Diminishing returns.... but you're right I should have said that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you.

```
awk '/searchTerm/{print $(NF-1)}' data/output/*>> output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have your lists in a file called filelist.txt you could just use the stdout from a cat command.

```
 awk -F "searchTerm" '{print NF-1}' `cat data/output/filelist.txt` >> output.txt`
```